# How to mock input function and check that an exception is raised

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a function that uses the `input` function as follows:

```
def get_valid_input(input_str: str, valid_options: tuple):
    while True:
        response = input(input_str)
        if response in valid_options:
            return response
        raise InvalidOptionException('Invalid option')
```

I need to test that the exception `InvalidOptionException`, which simple extends `Exception`, is raised when a response is not a valid option. I have the following test:

```
class UtilTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.input', lambda: 'a')
    def test_when_input_is_invalid_then_exception_is_raised(self):
        self.assertRaises(
            InvalidOptionException,
            get_valid_input,
            '', ('y', 'n')
        )
```

But, when I ran the test, I am getting the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 1179, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/Users/user/mathsistor/chumme/test/test_util.py", line 13, in test_when_input_is_invalid_then_exception_is_raised
    '', ('y', 'n')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 728, in assertRaises
    return context.handle('assertRaises', args, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 177, in handle
    callable_obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/mathsistor/chumme/util.py", line 14, in get_valid_input
    response = input(input_str)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` function takes one argument (the prompt string). To mock it you must use a function/lambda with one argument:

```
@patch('builtins.input', lambda _: 'a')
```

It's customary to use the underscore when you don't plan on using the argument.